# Length of specific vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

Assume we have two vectors $a,b \in\mathbb{R}^2$ with length $1$:

$a =\begin{pmatrix}x_a\\ y_a\end{pmatrix} \qquad 
b =\begin{pmatrix}x_b\\ y_b\end{pmatrix} \qquad \lvert a\lvert =\lvert b\lvert =1$

We now define a new vector $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$\sigma =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_a+x_b}{1+x_ax_b}\\ \frac{y_a+y_b}{1+y_ay_b}\end{pmatrix} $

I want to prove that the maximum length of $\sigma$ is $|\sigma|_{max} = \sqrt{2}$, and that the mimimum is $|\sigma|_{min} = 0$. I believe the maximum length is obtained when $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, and that the minimum length is obtained when the angle between $a$ and $b$ is $\pi$. I would like to prove this by finding a neat expression for the length of $\sigma$.

**Attempt at solution**

I assume (without loss of generality) that $a=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, and parametrize $b$ using the angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$, meaning $b=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta\end{pmatrix}$. I then simply plug into the definition of the norm of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

\begin{align}
|\sigma| &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{x_a+x_b}{1+x_ax_b}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y_a+y_b}{1+y_ay_b}\right)^2}\\
&= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1+\cos \theta}{1+\cos\theta}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sin\theta}{1}\right)^2}\\
&= \sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta}
\end{align}

This expression gives me the maximum length $\sqrt{2}$ when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$, but the minimum of this equation is $1$ when $\theta = 0, \pi$, which doesn't seem to be right, because if $a=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, = $b=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, corresponding to $\theta = \pi$, $\sigma$ becomes $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} $ which has length $0$. Could my mistake somehow related to the fact that we divide by $0$ for $\theta = \pi$ in the expression for $\sigma$?

Comment: A less controversial example for attaining 0 length is $x_a=y_a=-x_b=-y_b=\sqrt{2}/2$. Fact of matter is that $\sigma$ is ill-defined for $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(-1,0)$, because we divide by 0. Defining $\sigma$ as a limit may fail, since in your setting with fixed $a$ the limit is $\sigma=(1,1)$, but we can easily construct an approximating sequence with limit (0,0) by taking $a=-b$ with $a$ getting close to $(1,0)$. NB: I don't think it's obvious that you do not lose generality by fixing $a$.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I think you are right. I will look further into it